# Spring Hibernate @Transactional clarifications

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, transactional

I got a lot of confusion about @Transactional annotation.

1) If I use just declarative approach, is it enough to mark my service class/methods as @Transactional, or should I create the configuration beans and properties as shown in this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring)?

2) I need to use even programmatical approach in some situations, to be able to explicitly call flush() at a specific point of my workflow. In this case the former definitions of hibernate configs are mandatory?

Comment: `@Transactional` ensures that your method is encapsulated in a transaction. Sometimes, you have to call flush to "update" the state of your database in the middle of a transaction, like when you delete stuff from the database and then try to select from it. Without flushing after deleting, your select might not work properly.

Comment: @NathanHughes Considering that the info iside that config are quite generic, I was hoping Hibernate was able to "guess" them, i.e. reading application.properties where many of those settings are already specified. The second question would have made sense just if the first answer was not "Yes", like it seems to be.   
ayrton my transaction contains a cicle, inside which every iteration call a reference to an entity referred from the previous iteration. Then I got to explicitly call flush(), otherwise on second iteration Spring complains about the refer of the first one being still transient.

Comment: @NathanHughes what happens is that prior to committing, the PlatformTransactionManager will ask Hibernate to flush the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on a Spring Boot project, no, you won't need to explicitly declare the `SessionFactory` or the `PlatformTransactionManager` Beans. They'll be auto-configured for you.

Yes, putting the `Transactional` annotation on your class or method is enough for transactions to take place. Auto-commit should even be turned off automatically (for optimization purposes), in case it's not done at `DataSource` level.

For the "programmatical" part, you should consider staying on the annotation side. You can play with the *transaction propagation* strategies to isolate certain operations.

---

A couple important notes about using the declarative, annotation approach.

Remember to annotate `public` methods, if possible. Any other method visibility  cannot be managed via Java proxies or CGLIB proxies, thus, even though you won't notice it, those methods won't participate in the transaction context. For `protected` or `private` methods, you're forced to use AspectJ.

Remember also that when using proxies, self-invocation (& expecting a new transaction) doesn't work.

---

To use the programmatic approach, you just need to `Autowire` the `TransactionTemplate` or `PlatformTransactionManager` Bean.

The `PlatformTransactionManager` allows for more customization of the transaction, while `TransactionTemplate` is more of a utility object (which however can be modeled as needed).

Obviously, don't mix both approaches in the same methods call stack.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention I'm on Spring Boot.  In my case i doubt I can solve my problem through propagation strategies, can i access the autoconfigured session?

Comment: When you say "don't mix both approaches", do you mean that I shouldn't call a programmatical method from a declarative one?

Comment: @4javier Yes, don't use explicitly the TransactionManager inside a Transactional annotated method. While it works and you're able to have nested transactions, it becomes confusing, for you and for future maintainers.

Comment: Well, that's a bit of a problem. I choose a personal approach, where a method issue a transaction that in cascade could call another transaction and so on... I think I should rewrite my code to atomize every single transaction and store the returned ID, so as to be able to pass it to the next one called in a separate method.